# IValueConverter blocks prevents deletion

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listbox with image paths (ObservableCollection as source), and IValueConverter is turning them into the image thumbnails.

When I try to delete any of those files, I get the error:

"The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

```
public class UriToBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     try
     {
        BitmapFrame bit = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(value.ToString()), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
        if (bit.Thumbnail != null)
        {
         return bit.Thumbnail;
        }
        else
        {
          BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
          bi.BeginInit();
          bi.DecodePixelWidth = 200;                    
          bi.UriSource = new Uri(value.ToString());
          bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
          bi.EndInit();
          return bi;
         }
       }
     catch
     {
        return null;
     }
   }
```

How do I force-release the image, or force file deletion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use a `FileStream` and the [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx).

> Set the [CacheOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx) property to [BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) if you wish to close the stream after the [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) is created. The default [OnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) cache option retains access to the stream until the bitmap is needed, and cleanup is handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: That fixed the problem. As you said: FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); ... img.StreamSource = fileStream; Thank you very much!

Comment: In fact, just the first part work in the case image already has a thumbnail, but the second part did not, and now there are no images. When I put a break I can see: '(img.StreamSource).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' on the part img.StreamSource = fileStream;

Comment: That is because that property is not used for FileStreams, it's nothing to worry about, you just make it throw the exception by trying to get the property value. I don't know where your problem lies, maybe in the way you point to your image file.

Comment: I removed the Catch, and on .endinit I get: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

Comment: I've got it: I needed img.StreamSource.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin); after img.StreamSource = fileStream; since it seems the  BitmapFrame bit = BitmapFrame.Create(fileStream); already had read the stream. Thank you again and sorry for the trouble.